# Audio won't play on Mobile but works on Desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, audio, timer

I have a timer when it's three secodns, suppose to start an audio. The code works fine on desktop browsers but not on mobile. How can audio work on mobile?
It is with user gusture

HTML:

```
<div id="time"></div>
<button  onclick="startTimer(8);">START TIMER</button>
```

javascript:

```
function startTimer(timeInSeconds) {

    var audioExerciseEnd = new Audio('https://vardel.com/end_exe.mp3');
    var currentAudio = new Audio();

    const countDownFrom = timeInSeconds; // seconds
    const countDownBy = 1; // seconds

    display = document.querySelector('#time');

    const timer = moment.duration(countDownFrom, 's');
    
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      timer.subtract(countDownBy, "s");
    
      // timer.minutes() ... timer.seconds()
      // timer.milliseconds() to add milliseconds

      // moment.utc(timer.asMilliseconds()).format("mm:ss")
      // "mm:ss:SS" will include milliseconds
      
      display.textContent = moment.utc(timer.asMilliseconds()).format("mm:ss");
    
      if (timer.seconds() == 3) {
        currentAudio = audioExerciseEnd.cloneNode();
        currentAudio.play();
      }
    
      if (timer.asMilliseconds() == 0){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        document.querySelector('#time').textContent = "";
        console.warn("Times up!");
      }
      
      if (timer.asMilliseconds() !== 0) return;

    }, countDownBy * 1000);
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mustafamsy/1bymtgsh/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got the audio to play after some declared timer on the mobile browsers. If anyone is interested, here is what I did.

```js
    var audioExerciseEnd = document.createElement('audio');
    audioExerciseEnd.setAttribute('src', 'https://vardel.com/end_exe.mp3');

    function startTimer(timeInSeconds) {
    
        var currentAudio = new Audio();
        currentAudio = audioExerciseEnd.cloneNode();
        currentAudio.play();
        currentAudio.pause();
        
        const countDownFrom = timeInSeconds; // seconds
        const countDownBy = 1; // seconds
    
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    
        const timer = moment.duration(countDownFrom, 's');
        
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          timer.subtract(countDownBy, "s");
        
          // timer.minutes() ... timer.seconds()
          // timer.milliseconds() to add milliseconds
    
          // moment.utc(timer.asMilliseconds()).format("mm:ss")
          // "mm:ss:SS" will include milliseconds
          
          display.textContent = moment.utc(timer.asMilliseconds()).format("mm:ss");
        
          if (timer.seconds() == 3) {
            currentAudio.play();
          }
        
          if (timer.asMilliseconds() == 0){
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            document.querySelector('#time').textContent = "";
            console.warn("Times up!");
          }
          
          if (timer.asMilliseconds() !== 0) return;
    
        }, countDownBy * 1000);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
<button  onclick="startTimer(8);">START TIMER</button>
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mustafamsy/1bymtgsh/